# Performance problems with tkinter canvas

Tags: python, performance, tkinter

The following is my code for generating a 60x60 grid of Canvases.  I need to be able to individually target these items and change the colour individually, this however is a minimal version of what needs to be accomplished in my larget problem. Essentially what I'm asking is - because in terms of performance this grid is both slow to load, and makes the program overall sluggish, if there is any better way to do this in Tkinter that would be more efficient.
Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *

WINDOW = Tk()
WINDOW.state('zoomed')
grid = []

for n in range(0, 60):
    grid.append([])
    for i in range(0,60):
        grid[n].append(Canvas(WINDOW, bg="#222", height="10", width="10", highlightthickness="1"))
        grid[n][i].grid(row=n, column=i)
```

Comment: Is there something you're doing with these 3,600 10x10 canvases, that you couldn't be doing with one 600x600 canvas? What is it? If it's just "independently change the color of rectangular sections", you can do that easily with one canvas using rectangle items.

Comment: Are you able to target individual rectangles if you created them in a grid?

Comment: Yes. You can keep a reference to each of the values returned by `create_rect`, and change their colors later with `itemconfig`. You can also use the canvas' various `find` methods to locate rectangles based on coordinates. (although if your rects are in a nice grid pattern, it may be faster to find them with arithmetic, e.g. `row=y//rectangle_height; col=x//rectangle_width; rect=my_rectangle_references[col][row]`)

Comment: Im unsure how I'd make a grid of rectangles with specific height/width to the exact height/width of the canvas, I have tried with no success. Could you point me in the right direction?